# How to get function to search in (seemingly) nested environments (in R)?

Tags: r, function, user-defined-functions, environment

When I create a simple function that uses `mget` to call one object name assigned in .GlobalEnv and the other object having been assigned in the function's environment, I can't get the `mget` function to look in both environments.

Example:

```
> abc <- 5
> 
> f1 <- function(x) {
+ bcd <- 6
+ foo <- c('abc','bcd')
+ mget(foo)
+ }
>     
> f1()   
Error: value for ‘abc’ not found
```

**Is there a way to get the `mget` function in this example to find both objects?**

I've tried changing the `envir` argument for `mget` to many different things without any luck.

---

Note: I don't want to "change" the environment of the internal object (e.g., using `<<-` or `assign(bcd,envir=.GlobalEnv)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inherits=TRUE

```
f1 <- function(x) {
bcd <- 6
foo <- c('abc','bcd')
mget(foo, inherits=TRUE)
}
f1()
```